# How can I see which branch contains a certain commit, when working with atlassian jira and stash

Tags: git, jira, bitbucket-server

We just recently switched to a feature branch workflow with git. Our infrastructure is based on the Atlassian tools jira, bamboo and stash. 
All works pretty smooth and all three tools share their status. I can create a branch named like a jira ticket and trace its complete workflow through jira and bamboo until it is released.

But there seems to be one important missing feature: we often have the situation that a jira ticket has plenty of subtasks or some linked tickets. There will be no seperate branch for all the referened tickets, all commits go directly into the parent branch.
This is where we lose traceability of the subtasks; there seems to be no way in jira to see in which branch a referenced ticket has been resolved. 
We need to know which branch contains commits for certain tickets. When I have this information, I can deploy the branch for QS and present a list of all the new features/fixes that have been resolved in this branch.

Do you have similar problems or how would you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow your question entirely, but to list the branch(es) that contains a certain commit, do `git branch --contains <commit>`.

Comment: Hi, let me simplify my Question :) If a branch is ready for QS we need a list of all the resolved issues in that specific branch. And it would perfect for our workflow, if we can have that information in JIRA.

Answer (score 0):

If you include the issue keys in your commit messages, a link to the commit will show up on the Jira issue page, and likewise a link to the issue on the commit's page on Stash.

You may also find the [branch details](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.caseware.stash.branchDetails) plugin for Stash helpful: this will show what branches a commit is included in on the commit page.